# Generics with Generic Parameters and Abstract class

Tags: c#, silverlight, generics

I've got two generic base classes.  The second generic class has a constraint on its parameter of the first class.

```
abstract class FirstClass<T> {...}

abstract class SecondClass<U> where U : FirstClass {...}
```

This does not work, because FirstClass is not defined.  So I need to do this.

```
abstract class FirstClass<T> {...}

abstract class SecondClass<U, T> where U : FirstClass<T> {...}
```

Which works.  However, this makes implementing these abstract classes ugly.

```
class SomeClass {...}

class MyFirstClass : FirstClass<SomeClass> {...}

class MySecondClass : SecondClass<MyFirstClass, SomeClass> {...}
```

This seems redundant to me because I'm specifying SomeClass twice.  Is there a way to declare it in such a way that T from FirstClass is automatically the U for SecondClass.  What I would really like this to look like is.

```
class SomeClass {...}

class MyFirstClass : FirstClass<SomeClass> {...}

class MySecondClass : SecondClass<MyFirstClass> {...}
```

While I doubt this exact scenario is possible, is there a cleaner what to do what I am trying to do?

**Edit**

Several people have suggested making an IFirstClass interface.  But my definitions are closer to this.

```
class FirstClass<T>
{
    public T MyObj { get; set; }
}

class SecondClass<U, T> where U : FirstClass<T>
{
    U MyFirstClass { get; set; }
}
```

With an interface I cannot access MyFirstClass.MyObj from SecondClass.  While I could create a `object T MyObj { get; set; }` on IFirstClass, then use `new` to hide it, silverlight throws a fit in the binding if I do this.

Comment: While I don't mention silverlight in the question, this is a silverlight project.  I'm not sure if this would restrict the solution.

Comment: It would restrict the solution if you tried to marshal TypeOf<T> of WCF RIA Services as your POCO classes, since Generics cannot be exposed as WCF or WCF RIA Services (without some major workarounds).

Comment: Are you using any type specific info about FirstClass<U>? If not, what I tend to do in these instances is make FirstClass<U> match some IGenericFirstClass interface and then specify the constraint as IGenericFirstClass. It hides the type U dependency.

Comment: Are `U` and `T` different types?

Comment: @Stefan - I edited the code to try to clarify

Comment: Because of the compile-time nature of generics, there is the point where it just doesn't get any further. Then you have to go back to good old ugly downcasts...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are actually using the generic type arguments to `FirstClass` (as, from your edit, it sounds like you are), then no, what you're looking for is unfortunately not possible. The compiler does not differentiate between type arguments that are related and those that are not.

Comment: That's what I thought, but what do we have if we don't have hope?

Comment: @cadrell0: careers.stackoverflow.com ;) Seriously, though, don't forget to accept one of these answers. These are pretty much your only options.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience it is easiest to create non-generic interface to generic classes. It also solves the problem when you need to cast to the base class without knowing the generic type.

```
interface IFirstClass {...}

abstract class FirstClass<T> : IFirstClass {...}

abstract class SecondClass<T> where T : IFirstClass {...}
```

Comment: Please see my edits.  I haven't run into an issue where I need to cast to the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface that FirstClass implements.  Then you can constrain SecondClass to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

*This is actually an answer to [Interface with two generic parameters, solve one automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482969/interface-with-two-generic-parameters-solve-one-automatically) which has been marked as duplicate of this question.*

You could declare a bunch of interfaces with a specific Id type. Not a perfect solution, but simplifies the declaration of entity classes.

```
public interface IIntPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity>
        : IPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity, int>
    where TPersistentEntity : IPersistentEntity<int>
{
}

public interface IStringPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity>
        : IPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity, string>
    where TPersistentEntity : IPersistentEntity<string>
{
}
```

Then the `User` class can be declared like this:

```
public class UserService : IIntPersistentEntityService<User>
{
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You will get a compiler error if you have not the matching Id type.