# How to retrieve the argument of a generic base class at compile time? (i.e., without using Reflection)

Tags: c#, generics, metaprogramming

I want to implement a generic method to retrieve header/detail data from a database:

```
public static T RetrieveHeaderDetail<T>
    where T : Header<???>, new()
    // Where ??? means "what can I do here?"
{
    // ...
}
```

Here is the definition of the generic representing a document header:

```
public class Header<TDetail> where TDetail : class, new()
{
    public List<TDetail> Details;
}
```

And here are some instantiations:

```
public class RequestForQuotation : Header<RequestForQuotationDetail> { ... }
public class Order               : Header<OrderDetail>               { ... }
public class Invoice             : Header<InvoiceDetail>             { ... }
// ..
```

---

It is not hard to prove that, since .NET does not allow either multiple inheritance or "generic specialization" (which would allow a `Header<U>` to derive from some other `Header<V>`), for any specific `T`, there is at most one `U` such that `T` inherits (directly or indirectly) from `Header<U>`. Moreover, it is trivial to find the type `U`: iterate over `T`'s base types until you find an instance of `Header<U>`, and then just take the generic's argument! Still, C# wants me to specify the change my method's definition to the following:

```
public static T RetrieveHeaderDetail<T,U>
    where T : Header<U>, new()
    where U : class,     new()
{
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to get around this problem? I know it would be possible using Reflection, but I think it is a good practice to never do at runtime what could be done at compile time.

---

When I hit problems like this, I really, *really* miss C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question not too long ago.

[Generics with Generic Parameters and Abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555730/generics-with-generic-parameters-and-abstract-class)

Comment: What a pity! Absurd limitations like this make C# feel like a toy language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're after, but could you define an interface and use it to specify the constraint?

For example, we have something like this in a couple places:

```
public class Reader<T> where T : IInt32Id
{
   public T GetById(int Id)
   {
      // get by id
   }
}
```

Then I just use IInt32Id as an interface to derive all of my classes that have an int (as opposed to long) ID field.

Comment: The function's body relies on knowing the identity of `U`. I should have made it explicit. Sorry.