# Interface with two generic parameters, solve one automatically

Tags: c#, .net, generics

So I'm creating interfaces for my models and for my services in my project. The first interface I created was one for persistent entities, I set it up with a generic as the entity could have an Id of type 'int' or 'Guid'.

```
public interface IPersistentEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

After this, I went on to create the interface for the services that would deal with Persistent entities, which ended up like this.

```
public interface IPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity, T>
    where TPersistentEntity : IPersistentEntity<T>
{
    TPersistentEntity Get(T id);
}
```

Now, this works just fine, the thing is I'm curious if it is possible to set up the interface in a way where the type for the Id is solved automatically taking into account the entity used in the service.

With the code, I've done if I want to create a service I would need to do something like this.

```
public partial class User : IPersistentEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserService : IPersistentEntityService<User, int>
{
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I would like it to be something like

```
public class UserService : IPersistentEntityService<User>
{
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note I would no longer be indicating the type used in the class ("int" in this case), which is the thing I would like to be resolved automatically somehow.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55483300/880990

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following do what you're looking for?

```
public class UserService : IPersistentEntityService<User, int>
{
    public User Get<U>(U id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(U));
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IPersistentEntityService<TPersistentEntity, T>
    where TPersistentEntity : IPersistentEntity<T>
{
    TPersistentEntity Get<U>(U id);
}

void Main()
{
    UserService service = new UserService();
    service.Get<int>(23);
}
```